# SciChart TimeSpanAxis not showing VerticalLineAnnotation

Tags: scichart

Using SciChart v5.1.0.11299, I am trying to display VerticalLineAnnotations with a TimeSpanAxis as the X axis. I can display the vertical lines using a NumericAxis, but not with the TimeSpanAxis.

```
    <s:SciChartSurface ChartTitle="Values vs Time">
                        <s:SciChartSurface.XAxis>
                            <s:TimeSpanAxis AxisTitle="Time">
                                <s:TimeSpanAxis.VisibleRange>
                                    <s:TimeSpanRange Min="00" Max="00:10:00"/>
                                </s:TimeSpanAxis.VisibleRange>
                            </s:TimeSpanAxis>
                        </s:SciChartSurface.XAxis>
                        <s:SciChartSurface.YAxis>
                            <s:NumericAxis AxisTitle="Values"/>
                        </s:SciChartSurface.YAxis>
                        <s:SciChartSurface.Annotations>
                            <s:VerticalLineAnnotation Stroke="Orange" StrokeThickness="1" X1="00:00:10"/>
                            <s:VerticalLineAnnotation Stroke="Orange" StrokeThickness="1" X1="00:00:20"/>
                            <s:VerticalLineAnnotation Stroke="Orange" StrokeThickness="1" X1="00:01:00"/>
                            <s:VerticalLineAnnotation Stroke="Orange" StrokeThickness="1" X1="00:02:00"/>
                            <s:VerticalLineAnnotation Stroke="Orange" StrokeThickness="1" X1="00:05:00"/>
                        </s:SciChartSurface.Annotations>
                    </s:SciChartSurface>
```

However, the corresponding version as a NumericAxis does render the VerticalLineAnnotations:

```
                    <s:SciChartSurface ChartTitle="Values vs Not Time">
                        <s:SciChartSurface.XAxis>
                            <s:NumericAxis AxisTitle="Not Time">
                                <s:NumericAxis.VisibleRange>
                                    <s:DoubleRange Min="00" Max="1000"/>
                                </s:NumericAxis.VisibleRange>
                            </s:NumericAxis>
                        </s:SciChartSurface.XAxis>
                        <s:SciChartSurface.YAxis>
                            <s:NumericAxis AxisTitle="Values"/>
                        </s:SciChartSurface.YAxis>
                        <s:SciChartSurface.Annotations>
                            <s:VerticalLineAnnotation Stroke="Orange" StrokeThickness="1" X1="0010"/>
                            <s:VerticalLineAnnotation Stroke="Orange" StrokeThickness="1" X1="0020"/>
                            <s:VerticalLineAnnotation Stroke="Orange" StrokeThickness="1" X1="0100"/>
                            <s:VerticalLineAnnotation Stroke="Orange" StrokeThickness="1" X1="0200"/>
                            <s:VerticalLineAnnotation Stroke="Orange" StrokeThickness="1" X1="0500"/>
                        </s:SciChartSurface.Annotations>
                    </s:SciChartSurface>
```

This must be possible, but I cannot find an example of the required differences with regards to NumericAxis?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue here is you cannot set a TimeSpan easily in Xaml.

The property the of [VerticalLineAnnotation.X1](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/v5.x/The%20VerticalLineAnnotation%20Type.html) is IComparable, so the Xaml compiler picks it up as a string.

Try setting the X1 to a TimeSpan in code, an attached behaviour or binding to a ViewModel